# compiling own extension phpize - Cannot find config.m4

Tags: php, compiling, extension

I don't have config.m4, needed to compiling my extension. How can I get this file? I add that all question on this forum, explained that it should be.

Information when I try use phpize:

```
Cannot find config.m4.  Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in
the top level source directory of the module
```

Comment: You may need to enter the extension folder which contained config.m4 and then run phpize.